# Bancos de dados diferentes para a mesma aplicação asp.net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

Em um sistema para gerenciamento de clubes cada clube possui sua base de dados.

Existe uma classe *DAL* onde a mesma é encarregada de obter do `web.config` a *string* de *conexão da aplicação*.

Como garantir que no ato de login a aplicação carregasse a base de dados correta conforme o clube?

Comment: Você poderia descrever em detalhes como é a camada de acesso a dados da sua aplicação, no corpo da sua pergunta?

Comment: Possuo uma classe DAL onde a mesma é encarregada de obter do web.config a string de conexão da aplicação.

Comment: Então, mas isso é pouco. Precisamos de mais informações. Os databases são na mesma tecnologia (MySQL)? O banco de dados é agnóstico ou você usa objetos apenas do MySQL? Como o sistema carrega os dados? Você pode colocar um exemplo de uma seleção simples e de uma atualização simples?

Comment: Todas as bases de dados são MYSQL, no sistema são usados apenas objetos do mysql.

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira simples de fazer isso seria criar uma tabela especificando o banco de dados de cada clube (não estou falando para colocar dados de acesso ao banco), assim quando o usuário de algum clube realizar o login, você pode verificar em qual banco o clube pertence.

Ex.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abs,

Comment: Tudo bem. Esta é uma boa opção para o cenário em questão. Vou dar uma estudada nessa forma de acesso ao sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Voce poderia ter uma base de dados principal, onde ficarão tabelas comuns, como usuário por exemplo.

Nela terá a informação de qual é a base de dados utilizada por aquele usuário.

Consequentemente, você precisaria ter duas estruturas de DAL para suportar esta ação.

Mas....

Pelo que entendi todos os clubes tem a própria base de dados mas todas as bases ficam em um mesmo local, certo?
Se for isso, pensaria em unificar as bases, deixando uma unica base de dados e colocar as informações nos registros informando referente a qual clube aquele registro é.

Isso facilitaria, por exemplo, em ter informações consolidade de varios clubes do mesmo dono, por exemplo.

Comment: Todos os clubes tem sua própria base de dados, mas no caso dessa aplicação as bases ficam em locais diferentes, pois o sistema é publicado em cada clube de forma individual.

Comment: Neste caso, voce tem um aplicativoem cada clube, certo?

Seria ter um arquivo Ini com estas informações de acesso.
Em C# pelo menos tem o Web.config, onde voce pode colocar as informações de acesso a base de dados.

O que sugeri acima seria no caso de eu ter acesso a todos os clubes por exemplo. Mas não se aplica nesta situação que colocou agora